# Blender Hair Simulation is making a Wall

Tags: modifiers, particles, physics, edges, hair

In Blender 2.8, I made a grassy area and used hair simulation to create the grass. The only problem is that it seems to have created a wall on the edge of the plane. I have also noticed that as I increase the number of hair strands, the wall grows taller. Does anyone know how to fix this?[image]